# Are spring components instantiated when not autowired/injected?

Tags: java, spring

I have a `@Service` that's injected into a conditional bean. If the bean conditions is `false`, would the `@Service` be instantiated anyway? Do I need to mark it `@Lazy`?

Example:

```java
@Service
class MyService {
  public String doWork() {
    return "work";
  };
}
```

```java
interface MyComponent {
  String handle();
}
```

```java
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "features.enabled", havingValue = "false", matchIfMissing = true)
class MyNoopComponent implements MyComponent {
  @Override
  public String handle() {
    return "";
  };
}
```

```java
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "features.enabled", havingValue = "true")
class MyDefaultComponent implements MyComponent {
  private final Service service;

  @Autowired
  MyDefaultComponent(MyService service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  @Override
  public String handle() {
    return service.doWork();
  };
}
```

```yaml
# application.yaml
features:
  enabled: false
```

Comment: This seems pretty straight-forward to debug, but my guess would be you need use Spring's Lazy annotation on the service bean and wherever it is injected.

Comment: True, I was just a bit @Lazy right now 

Comment: I just see three possible scenarios. Lazy would defer instantiation until the bean is used. What's not clear is if without Lazy the IoC container is fully eager, e.g. it instantly instantiates all beans in the classpath or if it only instantiates ones that are needed by other beans by analysing the dependency graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a @Service that's injected into a conditional bean. If the bean conditions is false, would the @Service be instantiated anyway?

Yes, if you mark it as `@Service` and spring IOC container finds it during the startup (because it's a subject to component scanning) then it will load it, create the bean definition out of it, initialize the object, inject it's own dependencies and put onto the application context. From this standpoint it doesn't matter whether the bean is injected into other beans or not.

> Do I need to mark it @Lazy?

Usually lazy is used to "postpone" the initialization of bean till the point when its called first (read, its methods are invoked).

If you do not call this bean's method - you basically do not need to create.
@Michiel already provided one way to avoid loading this bean with annotation, another method is "unify" all the relevant beans in java configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(...)
public class MyConfig {

   @Bean
   public MyService myService() {
      return new MyService();
   }
   @Bean
   public MyDefaultComponent myDefaultComponent(MyService myService) {
        return new MyDefaultComponent(myService);
   }
}
```

This method allows specifying the conditional only once, so that if "tomorrow" you'll have even more beans to load - you'll know where to add them so that they will be loaded only upon certain value of your condition.

**Update 1**

Roughly the same effect can be achieved by using a custom stereotype annotation [See this tutorial for example](https://moelholm.com/blog/2016/10/15/spring-43-custom-annotations)

You can create your own annotation, say, `@FeatureXService` and annotated it with both `@ConditionalOnProperty` and regular `@Service`

Then you'll have to mark all the relevant beans with this annotation instead of regular `@Service` or `@Component`. The annotation looks like this:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "feature.x.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public @interface FeatureXService {
}
```

And the use it:

```
@FeatureXService
class MyService {...}

@FeatureXService
class MyDefaultComponent implements MyComponent {...}
```

This also allows specifying the `@ConditionalOnProperty` only once.

Comment: Yeah, what you say makes sense. I went through this solution as well, but then hoped that maybe I can avoid it. Both @Michiel's and your answers would work, but I'll mark your answer as correct since it's more common to group configurations like this.

Comment: I agree that this is the better answer, I totally overlooked that you can simply group the beans together in a configuration.

Comment: @DimitriosK. Please see an update on my answer, It looks like you're prefering the `Service/Component` annotations style to Java based configuration that I've initially mentioned in the answer...

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend defining the `MyService` bean as lazy for the purpose you describe, as you either need the bean or you don't. And although eager instantiation on a lazy bean would be skipped when the feature is disabled, once the feature is enabled the first request requiring the bean would have to wait until the bean is fully instantiated.

Your `ConditionalOnProperty` works fine, why not apply it twice by adding it to the `MyService` as well? Or you can create your own meta-annotation to prevent having to duplicate the annotation's attributes:

```java
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "features.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public @Interface ActiveWhenFeatureFlagEnabled {}
```

```java
@Component
@ActiveWhenFeatureFlagEnabled
class MyDefaultComponent implements MyComponent { ... }
```

```java
@Service
@ActiveWhenFeatureFlagEnabled
class MyService { ... }
```

Comment: That's what I initially had, just wanted to avoid the duplication of "conditional on property".